# How to check thread completed in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, download

I want to check whether a thread is completed or not.I want to download some data, when the download is completed then want to toast a message download completed .Here is my code and I used btn on click method to start the download.Now I want to check whether the download is completed.

```
public void startDownload(final int position) {

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            int Status = 0;

            public void run() {
                Log.v("thread", "thread rtun ");
                String urlDownload = MyArrList.get(position)
                        .get("VideoPathThum").toString();
                Log.v("log_tag", "urlDownload   ::: " + urlDownload
                        + "Position StartDownload ::: " + position);

                int count = 0;
                try {

                    URL url = new URL(urlDownload);
                    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                    conexion.connect();

                    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                    // Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
                            url.openStream());

                    // Get File Name from URL
                    String fileName = urlDownload.substring(
                            urlDownload.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
                            urlDownload.length());
                    download = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + "/download/");
                    if (!download.exists()) {
                        download.mkdir();
                    }
                    strDownloaDuRL = download + "/" + fileName;
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(strDownloaDuRL);

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;

                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

                        if (Thread.interrupted() == true) {
                            Log.v("log_tag", " interrupt");
                            output.flush();
                            output.close();
                            input.close();
                            updateStatus(position, 0);
                            SetMainProgressbar();
                            break;
                        }

                        total += count;
                        Status = (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);
                        output.write(data, 0, count);

                        TestScrollNewDownloadActivity.this
                                .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        updateStatus(position, Status);
                                        SetMainProgressbar();
                                        // BusyExtMemory();

                                    }
                                });
                    }
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }
        };

        tr = new Thread(runnable);
        tr.start();
        trlist.set(position, tr);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks All of my question reply .i Try async task.and check it.

Comment: Please check my edited answer i have passed position in AsyncTask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AysncTask() for this. It better compared to thread

```
DownloadAsync download = new DownloadAsync(position);
download.execute();


private class DownloadAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    int pos;

    public incidentDetailAsync(int position) {

        pos = position;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try {
            progressDilaog = ProgressDialog.show(ActivityA.this,
                    "", "Loading", true, false);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
              String urlDownload = MyArrList.get(position)
                    .get("VideoPathThum").toString();
            Log.v("log_tag", "urlDownload   ::: " + urlDownload
                    + "Position StartDownload ::: " + position);

            int count = 0;
            try {

                URL url = new URL(urlDownload);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();

                int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                // Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
                        url.openStream());

                // Get File Name from URL
                String fileName = urlDownload.substring(
                        urlDownload.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
                        urlDownload.length());
                download = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/download/");
                if (!download.exists()) {
                    download.mkdir();
                }
                strDownloaDuRL = download + "/" + fileName;
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(strDownloaDuRL);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

                    if (Thread.interrupted() == true) {
                        Log.v("log_tag", " interrupt");
                        output.flush();
                        output.close();
                        input.close();
                        updateStatus(position, 0);
                        SetMainProgressbar();
                        break;
                    }

                    total += count;
                    Status = (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);
                    output.write(data, 0, count);

                    TestScrollNewDownloadActivity.this
                            .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    updateStatus(position, Status);
                                    SetMainProgressbar();
                                    // BusyExtMemory();

                                }
                            });
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDilaog.dismiss();

        Toast.makeText(ActivityA.this,
                "Successfully Download", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Place the code you want to run on the separate thread in doInBackground. Place the code you want to run on the UI thread after the separate thread finishes in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AysncTask()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Call using :  `new AsyncAction().execute(null,null,null);`

```
private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {
         public boolean status=false;
        private ProgressDialog pd;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
              {

            // download code

 String urlDownload = MyArrList.get(position)
                        .get("VideoPathThum").toString();
                Log.v("log_tag", "urlDownload   ::: " + urlDownload
                        + "Position StartDownload ::: " + position);

                int count = 0;
                try {

                    URL url = new URL(urlDownload);
                    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                    conexion.connect();

                    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                    // Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
                            url.openStream());

                    // Get File Name from URL
                    String fileName = urlDownload.substring(
                            urlDownload.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
                            urlDownload.length());
                    download = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + "/download/");
                    if (!download.exists()) {
                        download.mkdir();
                    }
                    strDownloaDuRL = download + "/" + fileName;
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(strDownloaDuRL);

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;

                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

                        if (Thread.interrupted() == true) {
                            Log.v("log_tag", " interrupt");
                            output.flush();
                            output.close();
                            input.close();
                            updateStatus(position, 0);
                            SetMainProgressbar();
                            break;
                        }

                        total += count;
                        Status = (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);
                        output.write(data, 0, count);

                        TestScrollNewDownloadActivity.this
                                .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        updateStatus(position, Status);
                                        SetMainProgressbar();
                                        // BusyExtMemory();

                                    }
                                });
                    }
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }


                  status=true;

            } 
              catch (Exception e) 
              {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {

           pd.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(ActivityA.this,
                "Successfully Download", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(ticket_detail.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Nirav but i want to  pass postion in async task.